# MacBook Pro 15 Early 2012 very slow

Tags: performance, macbook-pro, optimize

My Mac machine, is becoming lazy day by day.. booting it takes around 50-130 seconds.
No idea how to fix it or do I need to run any optimization software?

Machine freezes also and eats RAM too much

EDITED

[image]

[image]

Comment: That boot time isn't unusual, but without knowing what exact hardware you have, or any specifics about what processes your Mac runs, we can't help you any further, I'm afraid. There is optimization software for OS X, but it's generally not advised to use something like that—most of these are rather shady. Can you show us what Activity Monitor shows? What applications take unusual memory or CPU time?

Comment: @slhck, I have updated the question, but the boot time it too long, even my B960 processor PC running windows 7 boots faster then my Mac:(

Comment: @kaibuki Yeah well Windows 7 was designed for doing work so they made it boot up in a reasonable amount of time. Wouldn't want people being unproductive now, would we? Anyway, you should look at the other memory metrics for processes. I had Messages chewing up something like 12GB but the `Real Mem` was quite low. Click *View* and then *Columns*.

Comment: Is this the boot time between the power button and the login screen or the time between the login screen and being able to work (or both)? Is there a specific reason why you didn't apply all the software updates?

Answer (score 1):

Boot time increases with each major update, in my experience. Plus along the way you install services like dropbox or whatever that seem innocent, but somehow they add to the startup time, just like with Windows. A 2 minute startup time is ridiculous, but it's reality, for me as well.

If you really want to test, reinstall your system. You can keep your account as it is. Reinstalling means that the system library is clean, and all custom apps are removed. Startup with a different account, and see how long that takes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should quit subjective valutation and use some benchmark software to understand if you really have a problem.

I'd use Geekbench or anything similar (http://www.primatelabs.com/geekbench/) and once you have your results I'd look in Geekbench database to find out if Mac identical to yours have identical performances (http://browser.primatelabs.com/).

Only then I'd point my finger and I'd start to find out the culprit (disk? ram? applications that do something at startup?).